# Method not allowed 405 POST ASP.NET CORE 5.0 WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net5

I am running two projects at the same time, on my mvc project when I call my `PaymentServiceAsync()` method, when it hits the line `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` it the variable `response` says **Method not allowed (405)** I can't seem to figure out why it is doing so if I have it set correctly.

Here is my PaymentServiceAsync() method:

```
        public async Task<string> PaymentServiceAsync()
        {
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("api/paymentservices/payment");

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return result;
        }
```

Now in my asp.net core web api project this is my controller that it calls:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Nest;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using PaymentService.API.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace PaymentService.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PaymentServicesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private String _connectionString;
        private IElasticClient _elasticClient = new ElasticClient();
        private readonly ILogger<PaymentServicesController> _logger;

        public PaymentServicesController(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<PaymentServicesController> logger)
        {
            _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("Default");
            _logger = logger;
        }


        // POST api/<PaymentServices>
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("payment")]
        public async Task<int> Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Payment method involked!");
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nOpening connection...");

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into applog(ElkLog_id, CorrelationId, DateCreated, MessageTemplate, Message) values(@elk_id, @cid, @dt, @mt, @m)", connection);

                string indexName = "customer-simulation-es-app-logs*";
                var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
                connectionSettings.DefaultIndex(indexName);
                connectionSettings.EnableDebugMode();
                _elasticClient = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);


                // this will tell us how much hits/results there is based on the following criteria 
                var countResponse = _elasticClient.Count<EsSource>(c => c
                     .Query(q => q
                         .Bool(b => b
                             .Should(
                                   m => m
                                   .Match(ma => ma
                                       .Field(fa => fa.level)
                                       .Query("Error")),
                                   m => m
                                   .Match(ma => ma
                                       .Field(fa => fa.level)
                                       .Query("Information")))
                             .Filter(f => f.DateRange(dr => dr
                             .Field("@timestamp")
                                 .GreaterThanOrEquals("2021-06-18T16:34:45.701-05:00")
                                 .LessThanOrEquals("2021-07-18T16:34:45.701-05:00")))
                             .MinimumShouldMatch(1)))).Count;


                Console.WriteLine($"\nDocuments in index: {countResponse}");

                Console.WriteLine($"Open new pit");
                var openPit = await _elasticClient.OpenPointInTimeAsync(indexName, d => d.KeepAlive("1m"));
                var pit = openPit.Id;

                Console.WriteLine($"Read all docs from index ..");
                // we will start reading docs from the beginning
                var searchAfter = DateTimeOffset.MinValue;


                var elkLogId = "";
                var correlationId = "";
                var dateCreated = default(DateTimeOffset);
                var messageTemplate = "";
                var message = "";
                int numrows = 0;

                try
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    Console.WriteLine("\nConnection successful!");

                    while (true)
                    {
                        ........

                       

                        numrows = await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

                        

                        command.Parameters.Clear();

                        

                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("\nAll logs have been recorded to the database successfully!");

                    connection.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine("\nConnection closed....");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Close pit");
                    var closePit = await _elasticClient.ClosePointInTimeAsync(d => d.Id(pit));
                }

                return numrows;
            }
        }

       
    }
}
```

`appsettings.json`

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;Database=ElasticSearchService;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using get request remove [post] from api

```
[Route("~api/paymentservices/payment/{value}")]
 public async Task<int> Post(string value)
```

and fix the request

```
//--init http client with base url

var baseUri= @"http:...";
    
    using HttpClient client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUri) };
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
.....
string value="test"; //replace with your value

var response = await client.GetAsync("api/paymentservices/payment/"+value);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
.....
}
```

or you can try post method as well, in this case try to use  action

```
[Route("~api/paymentservices/payment")]
 public async Task<int> Post(string value)
```

and code

```
var baseUri= @"http:....";
    
    using HttpClient client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUri) };
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    string value="test"; //replace with your value

    Dictionary<string, string> packet = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    packet.Add("value", value);
    

    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(packet), UTF8Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    
    var response = await client.PostAsync("api/paymentservices/payment", content);
    
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var stringData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        .....
    }
```

Comment: If I remove the `[post]` from the api wouldn't that cause it to be a GET method? So ultimately I am wanting to call that API from my asp.net mvc project and that API should write to my database. Thats why I did it as `GET` and used `POST`. Should I make the response use `PostAsync`?

Comment: @MarkCo It doesn' matter what do you use post or get since you have only one string value as an input parameter. You will have the same result. I see a lot of bugs in your get request, but post request is more complicated. It is up to you.

Comment: I see, so if I am using a get method in the API and in the `PaymentServiceAsync()` I am using the `.GetAsync()` I can still perform the contents of my `Post()` method inside of the API? As in I can still insert data into the database?

Comment: @MarkCo,  yes it doesn' t matter what method to get data you use.  Result will be the same. The post method  is usually used  when you have a lot of parameters that you can't put it the query string, otherwise get is much more simple and reliable. You can get result from api  using [get] method even without application, just using the browser.

Comment: I understand thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "Post" method you are trying to attempt "Get" verbs action in the code.

> var response = await
> _httpClient.GetAsync("api/paymentservices/payment");

As per your requirement these are payment related code and if you are really thinking about security then use POST method instead of GET.

Here we have created **"IServiceProvider"** (ASP.NET Core provides a built-in service container, IServiceProvider.) instance *"_serviceProvider"* through constructor dependency injection. This is one of the example of how to call POST method in ASP.NET Core app.

Instead of HttpClient use IHttpClientFactory in ASP.Net Core App, Using IHttpClientFactory in a DI-enabled app avoids:

- Resource exhaustion problems by pooling HttpMessageHandler instances.
- Stale DNS problems by cycling HttpMessageHandler instances at regular
  intervals.

**Try this:**

```
using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var clientFactory = (IHttpClientFactory)scope.ServiceProvider
             .GetService(typeof(IHttpClientFactory));
            var client = clientFactory.CreateClient();
            //PaymentObject
            string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paymentObject);
            var httpContent = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:3978/");
            var response = await client.PostAsync("api/paymentservices/payment", httpContent);
       }
```

**Reference:**

1. [IHttpClientFactory Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: So I want to use that post API I would need to use `PostAsync()` correct if I am wanting to send the certain things into my DB?

Comment: I have given one example instead of get you need to use post method because these are secure object.

Comment: What exactly is `_serviceProvider` is that apart of dependency injection for microsoft.extensions? The payment object, if those are logs from elasticsearch, would it just be my `numrows`?

Comment: Defines a mechanism for retrieving a service object "IServiceProvider", This will help you to inject dependency injection so you can avoid unneccary implementation.

Comment: I have updated the solution with IServiceProvider details.

Comment: Get method and httpclient are bad ideas for payment related implementation. You can try the above solution as an answer. Because socket exception will throw for HTTP client implementation for your accepted solution and this is the reason Microsoft introduced IHttpClientFactory for .Net Core 3.1 above apps to reduce the socket risk and improve the performance.